# Issue with using Macros in SBT

Tags: scala, macros, sbt

Assume you have two SBT projects, one called A and another called B

A has a subproject called macro, that follows the exact same pattern as showed here (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Macro-Projects.html). In other words, A has a subproject macro with a package that exposes a macro (lets called it macrotools). Now both projects, A and B, use the macrotools package (and A and B are strictly separate projects, B uses A via dependancies in SBT, with A using publish-local)

Now, A using A's macrotools package is fine, everything works correctly. However when B uses A macrotools package, the following error happens

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.monetise.waitress.types.Married$.<init>()V from class com.monetise.waitress.types.RelationshipStatus$
```

For those wondering, the macro is this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/13672520/1519631, so in other words, this macro is what is inside the macrotools package

This is also related to my earlier question [Macro dependancy appearing in POM/JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400538/macro-dependancy-appearing-in-pom-jar), except that I am now using SBT 0.13, and I am following the altered guide for SBT 0.13

The code being referred to above is, in this case, this is what is in B, and A is `com.monetise.incredients.macros.tools` (which is a dependency specified in build.sbt)

```
package com.monetise.waitress.types
import com.monetise.ingredients.macros.tools.SealedContents

sealed abstract class RelationshipStatus(val id:Long, val formattedName:String)
case object Married extends RelationshipStatus(0,"Married")
case object Single extends RelationshipStatus(1,"Single")

object RelationshipStatus {
//  val all:Set[RelationshipStatus] = Set(
//      Married,Single
//  )

  val all:Set[RelationshipStatus] = SealedContents.values[RelationshipStatus]
}
```

As you can see, when I use whats commented, the code works fine (the job of the macro is to fill the Set with all the case objects in an ADT). When I use the macro version, i.e. `SealedContents.values[RelationshipStatus]` is when I hit the `java.lang.IllegalAccessError`

**EDIT**

Here are the repos containing the projects
https://github.com/mdedetrich/projectacontainingmacro
https://github.com/mdedetrich/projectb

Note that I had to do some changes, which I forgot about earlier. Because the other project needs to depend on the macro as well, the following 2 lines to disable macro publishing have been commented out

```
publish := {},
publishLocal := {}
```

In the build.scala. Also note this is a runtime, not a compile time error

**EDIT 2**
Created a github issue here https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/874

Comment: If you could publish your SBT projects to GitHub and provide a reproduction scenario (e.g. "do `sbt compile` and you'll face a compilation error"), I could take a look at what's going on.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako, the projects have been put on github, check the edit. Note that these are runtime errors, not compile errors. The code compiles fine, its just when you try to run it that you run into issues

Comment: Thank you! I will try to take a look soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is unrelated to SBT. It looks like the macro from [Iteration over a sealed trait in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671734/iteration-over-a-sealed-trait-in-scala/13672520#comment27752955_13672520) that you're using has a bug. Follow the link to see a fix.